# using class objects in a for loop

Tags: python, class, object

I need to use my objects of a class in a `for` loop, but get an error.

Here's the code:

```
class Citizen():
    type='Citizen'
    colony='init'
    def __init__(self,value1,value2):
        self.name=value1
        self.gender=value2
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.name)
    def print_citizen(self,colonyname):
        for i in self.Citizen:
            if (Citizen.colony==colonyname) :
                print(i.name,' | Citizen | ',i.gender)
```

and it throws this error:

```
for i in self.Citizen:
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Citizen'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How are you calling `print_citizen`? Somehow `self` is set to a string, not a Citizen.

Comment: Are you doing `Citizen.print_citizen("Colony")`? That's not correct. You need to create a `Citizen` object with `object = Citizen("Fred", "male")`, and then do `object.print_citizen("Colony")`

Comment: Of course, even if you do that, you'll still have a problem because you never set `self.Citizen` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but this would work this way:

```
class Citizen():
    type='Citizen'
    colony='init'

    def __init__(self,value1,value2):
        self.name=value1
        self.gender=value2

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.name)

    def print_citizen(self,colonyname):
        if (self.colony==colonyname) :
          print(self.name,' | Citizen | ',self.gender)
```

Then:

```
myCitizen = Citizen("Bob", "Male")
myCitizen.print_citizen(colonyname)
```